# Is it possible to remove the focus from a text input when a page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site with one textfield for search however I dont want the focus to be on it when the page loads however it is the only text input on the form, is it possible to remove the focus?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

A jQuery solution would be something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('input').blur();
});
```

Comment: actually this code has a typo

        $(function(){
           $('input).blur();
        });

Comment: Are there any CSS3 methods that do this same exact process?

Comment: @klewis no there is no method in CSS for blurr

Comment: The question had a "jQuery" tag, but blur() and focus() are JavaScript DOM Methods so they should be available with most frameworks (like they are with jQuery) as well as with straight JavaScript.  (CSS has a ":focus" pseudo-class selector, but that's more like an adjective rather than a verb.)

Answer (score 96):

use `document.activeElement.blur();`

example at http://jsfiddle.net/vGGdV/5/ that shows the currently focused element as well.

Keep a note though that calling `blur()` on the body element in IE will make the IE lose focus

Comment: It work as exprected in Safari MAC OS X 10.12, iPhone iOS 9,10,10.2! @Gaby aka G. Petrioli

Comment: @ArturMustafin thanks for the heads up. Good to know.

Answer (score 15):

I would add that [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) has a built-in [`.blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/blur) method as well.

Here's a demo using both `.focus` and `.blur` which work in similar ways.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#myInput");
```

```html
<input id="myInput" value="Some Input">

<button type="button" onclick="input.focus()">Focus</button>
<button type="button" onclick="input.blur()">Lose focus</button>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `.blur()` method. See http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function() {
 $("#MyTextBox").blur();
});
```